# Is it possible to develop for Office 365 (confusion due to new-to-365)

Tags: excel, outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm not even sure if it's possible at all. Earlier, I've been designing addons to Outlook and Excel (using VSTO and VBA). Now, my company got into this Office 365 thinking and we have all our environment online, no local software at all, strictly and only web client approach.

It's got its advantages. But the downside is that out support have no clue how it works (except to tell us to click the settings and look for options, sigh). So, I wonder if it's possible to develop and somehow upload my own customizations (NB we have no servers in the cloud - everything is provided on SAS basis).

Suppose I'd like to:

1. mark all emails from a certain sender with yellow background in the list in Outlook, or
2. highlight every occurrence of the word "*donkey*" in the text mass in Word.
   Is it doable at all?

I've googled for it but all I can see is that there's an API and that we need to runt the stuff on our own servers. Am I just confusing myself here?

Comment: I've added the fairly new [office-js] tag to your question. I believe that questions for programming for Office 365 will receive focused attention there.

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you, it's probably a wise edition. However, "JS"? Are we talking JavaScript? As in - instead of a compilable C# DLL that I upload, I code JS? That's a new...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you have O365 subscription, you actually still have the ability to download all desktop version of Office. So your existing customizations should still work on Desktop version of Office.

Second,check out Office Add-in on [dev.office.com](http://dev.office.com/getting-started). Office Add-ins extend the functionality of Office with a web app that lives within Office applications. They work similar to traditional VBA add-ons and we have a rich set of API that helps you interact with Office. This is basically a web app with JavaScript, HTML and CSS. You can build it with any tools you are familiar with and host it anywhere. It is really easy to build and let us know if you have more questions.

Thanks,
Sky

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right, still. I've been on that site while googling but I get confused by the choices. The first one seems to be for **external** application that integrate with Office 365, the second is for desktop version Office and the last one is for SharePoint. Which one/where is the info regarding development for Office 365 (online version only)? Is it right there and I'm just missing it?! Please advise.

Comment: Konrad, you want the middle of the three that are on the page Sky linked to. The new "add-ins" can be hosted in a SharePoint catalog, a network share or the "Store" (public - which is probably not relevant for you at this point). And it's only "easy" if you already know JavaScript, etc. Also, the APIs aren't (yet) as fully developed as the traditional object model, so you may not be able to migrate everything your current Office extensions are doing immediately.

Comment: Konrad, The Office Add-in works not only with Office Desktop. It actually runs wherever Office runs. In general it works on Office Desktop, Office Online, and Office for iOS. You can find the full platform compatibility here on https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj220082.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for highlighting messages from specific senders would be to use the [Outlook REST APIs](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted) to access the messages and either stamp a specific category color on the messages, or a flag to highlight the message in the list view.  That approach would work across both Web, Outlook, and even Mobile (if you use flags).  The new Outlook add-in model is powerful and works for Outlook on the Web, as well as Outlook on Windows, but doesn't allow you to update the colors of the list view add-ins.

Comment: How about coloring every occurrence of a certain word in Word? Is that possible? I'm **very** unclear on how to upload such a customization into the web versions (we're using exclusively web clients, nothing's installed on the desktops at all).